# OCaml Pattern Matching For Custom Type

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am new to OCaml. I am working on a project that has the following custom type:

```
type ('a, 'b) holder = 'a * 'a * 'b option
```

I am trying to fold a function over a holder list but cannot figure out how to pattern match> I need to be able to access the values within the holder as well. I have tried:

```
match currently_holder with
|[] -> acc
|(a0, a1, b0) -> a1::acc
```

I appreciate any help. As stated I am pretty inexperienced and have just begun using custom types. Thank you!

Comment: It's better as a practice to also include the errors that we see. Very helpful are errors while programming.

Answer (score 3):

Your example code doesn't make sense because the two patterns have completely different types. The pattern `[]` matches a list (specifically, an empty list) and the pattern `(a0, a1, b0)` matches a 3-tuple.

Your type `holder` is a 3-tuple, so only the second pattern is valid.

Assuming that `currently_holder` is a value of type `('a, 'b) holder`, you can match it like this to distinguish the two cases for the third element (`None` vs. `Some x`):

```
match currently_holder with
| (a0, a1, None) -> (* Case where b is not present *)
| (a0, a1, Some b0) -> (* Case where b is present *)
```

However, you don't need a `match` expression to extract the parts of a tuple:

```
let (a0, a1, b0opt) = currently_holder in
.  .  .
```

Here `b0opt` is bound to a value of type `'b opt`.

Comment: Further, if you only needed, for example, the first element of that tuple, you can use `_` for values you don't care about.  `let (a, _, _) = currently_holder`